# Node.Js - Get windows username

Tags: node.js, active-directory

I am trying to get the windows username of the machine that is running my node.jS app (the app is always running on a Windows machine).

How can I get the current windows username using Node.Js?

I am trying to find something similar to **WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name** in C# for node.js, or **whoamI** command in CMD.

Comment: It wasn't first clear here when you are using the term windows you were referring to the operating system.

Comment: The current Windows username is not what you want (that would be the user running the server process).  You need NTLM authentication.

Comment: Since Nodejs v6, one can use `os.userInfo().username` See [os.userInfo](https://nodejs.org/dist/v6.0.0/docs/api/os.html#os_os_userinfo_options)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Since Node v6 (2016-04), you can just use [os.userInfo](https://nodejs.org/dist/v6.0.0/docs/api/os.html#os_os_userinfo_options) :

```
var os = require('os');
os.userInfo().username
```

---

To get the current logged-in username:

```
var path = require('path');
var userName = process.env['USERPROFILE'].split(path.sep)[2];
var loginId = path.join("domainName",userName);
console.log(loginId);
```

Comment: didn't worked for me under linux
but i could found the user under 
``process.env.USER``

Comment: Is "domainName" for me under Win7

Comment: I was able to get from process.env.USERDOMAIN process.env.USERNAME

Comment: Thanks afreeland! I used process.env.USERNAME and was able to username without requiring path.

Comment: Can we use the same in react app?

Answer (score 8):

I understand that this will not give the client user of a web app as OP asked, but this question is very high in the search results for trying to get the logged in user when running a Node application locally.

You can reproduce the `<domain>\<username>` output of `whoamI` and `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()` with environment variables in Windows.

`process.env.USERDOMAIN + '\\' + process.env.USERNAME`

If you'd rather use `USERPROFILE`:

`process.env.USERDOMAIN + '\\' + process.env.USERPROFILE.split('\\').pop()`

Answer (score 4):

Although node has the built in operating system function `os` and the `os.hostname()` to return the host name, you will need to access the client's hostname in ASP.NET or the language of your choice.  You can't do that in node since it is running on the server side and has nothing to do with the client's local info.

```
> require('os')
> os.hostname()
```

**Look at this question**

[Determine Client's Computer Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444592/determine-clients-computer-name)

**GET CLIENT HOST NAME IN ASP.NET AKA CLIENT SIDE**

`System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry( Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_HOST"]).HostName;`

**SPOON FEED FOR THE LAZY**

```
string IP = Request.UserHostName;
string compName = CompNameHelper.DetermineCompName(IP);

code from compnamehelper:

public static string DetermineCompName(string IP)
    {
        IPAddress myIP = IPAddress.Parse(IP);
        IPHostEntry GetIPHost = Dns.GetHostEntry(myIP);
        List<string> compName = GetIPHost.HostName.ToString().Split('.').ToList();
        return compName.First();
    }
```

[MICROSOFT DOCUMENTATION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143996%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Down voted because you seem to have over looked what is being asked. He is looking to get the current users username.

Comment: Down vote removed. I assumed he would be having his clients run node... I don't seem to understand the use case he is going for.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however Os.hostname returns the computer name, not the userID in Active Directory.

Answer (score 3):

Someone has created a module called [username](https://www.npmjs.com/package/username) that does all of the hard work for you.

You use it like

```
var username = require('username');

console.log( username.sync() );
```

Comment: That doesn't sound very future proof or as simple as using somebody else's module.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are stating that you have a Asp.NET application, and would like to use Node.js to determine the current users username, and then submit it to your Asp.NET application.

I do not develop on Windows though from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17814799/windows-user-name-variable-and-javascript) I believe this may be stored as an environment variable. `process.env` is a javascript map / dict of environment variables and likely contains the users username.

Alternatively you can parse it from the users home directory as such :

`var path = require('path');
var username = path.sep(process.env['USERPROFILE'])[2];`

The question I linked above implies that `USERPROFILE` resolves to `C:\Users\USERNAME\`. I then split the path and take the 3rd element, being the username.

Again, I do not have a windows machine and could not confirm this. Hope this sets you down the right path though.

Cheers.

Answer (score -2):

Since Node v6 (2016-04), you can just use os.userInfo :

To get the current logged-in username:

```
var path = require('path');
var userName = process.env['USERPROFILE'].split(path.sep)[2];
var loginId = path.join("domainName",userName);
console.log(loginId);
```

once we get the username from above code.we can't able to hit this username api by client side.it showing 401 res for this method

Comment: This code is the same as the [highest-rated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28482722/18069264).