# Pass Windows Username to my react/nodejs application

Tags: node.js, reactjs, iis, windows-authentication

I configured my React application on an IIS and enabled windows authentication on it, now when opening my React application it asks for windows login, but now I have a new problem, because I cannot receive the user name in my application javascript.
My backend was developed in Javascript with Nodejs.

Comment: It is impossible to get the name of current window user in the frontend JS.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9518092/javascript-how-to-get-the-name-of-the-current-user/9518139#9518139
Besides, the server-side might be able to get the windows identity.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27895127/node-js-getting-windows-username